# Run mysql queries in ubuntu 10.04 shell (cmd) stored in a files (desc order by filename)

Tags: 10.04, command-line, mysql

I have a folder with about 40 SQL scripts with varying names, 
All using the pattern *`number description`*`.sql`.
The file number consist of 2 digits and goes from 01 to 40, not all numbers in this range included.

I would like to iterate over this folder with files and run them via mysql cmd in a DESC filename order.

How can I run them all via `mysql cmd` in order of descending file number? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to run the scripts in ascending lexicographic order, you could do

```
for x in *.sql; do
  mysql <"$x"
done
```

Listing the files in descending order can be done easily in [zsh](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zsh) [image: Install zsh], thanks to the `O` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), but there is no corresponding feature in bash. At a zsh prompt:

```
for x in *.sql(On); do
  mysql <"$x"
done
```

By the way, if your numbers didn't have a leading 0, you could use `(nOn)` here, to sort `9 foo.sql` before `10 bar.sql`.

Using only programs that are in a default installation (plus `mysql`), you can list the files, sort them as desired with [`sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/sort.1.html) (or directly reverse the order with [`tac`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/tac.1.html)), and iterate over the result.

```
for x in *.sql; do echo "$x"; done |
tac |
while IFS= read -r script; do mysql <"$script"; done
```

Comment: I have used the zsh solution. Works like a charm :)
Thank you for the full answer.